# Cannot Find Label Control In Repeater Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, repeater

I want to take the Label control with ID `TextLabel` in the code behind, but this give me the following exception `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` The exception is on this line of code in code behind file:

```
  Label label = e.Item.FindControl("TextLabel") as Label;

  string text = label.Text;
```

What mistake I made here ? How to find "TextLabel" control in code behind ?

aspx code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="UserPostRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="UserPostRepeater_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Label ID="TextLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

code-behind:

```
protected void UserPostRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    BlogProfileEntities blogProfile = new BlogProfileEntities();
    Label label = e.Item.FindControl("TextLabel") as Label;
    string text = label.Text;
}
```

Comment: Check your html output. You'll probably see that it gives it an ID like TextLabel_1, being the reason you cannot find it using that ID.

Answer (score 5):

When using the `ItemDataBound` you need to check the type of repeater item - `e.Item.ItemType`.

It needs to be either `ListItemType.Item` or `ListItemType.AlternatingItem` - these are the templates where the label exists.

```
protected void UserPostRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    BlogProfileEntities blogProfile = new BlogProfileEntities();

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
      Label label = e.Item.FindControl("TextLabel") as Label;
      string text = label.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or better to just check if dataitem != null

Comment: @TomasVoracek - `FindControl` is expensive. It is better to only call if when it is reasonable to expect it to be there.

Comment: Why create a new instance _before_ checking the item type? Seems a waste of resources.

Comment: @ShaiCohen - The type isn't even used in the method - might as well ask why create it at all. I just based my example on what was posted.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for the correct `ItemType` in `ItemDataBound` since it is called for **every** item, so for the  `Header` first.

```
protected void UserPostRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
     // This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.
      // Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
      {
         Label label = e.Item.FindControl("TextLabel") as Label;
         string text = label.Text;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> You need to specify what type of `ItemType` it is. This will work in your case:

```
protected void UserPostRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)  // Add this
    {
     Label label = e.Item.FindControl("TextLabel") as Label;
     string text = label.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why create a new instance _before_ checking the item type?